# Creating an Accordion with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

Trying to open and close a accordion with JavaScript. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. I really can't find the mistake (I know there is one!!!)

```js
const sContent = document.getElementsByClassName("content"),
  sHeader = document.querySelectorAll(".header");

function toggleSki() {
  let itemClass = this.parentNode.className;

  for (i = 0; i < sContent.length; i++) {
    sContent[i].className = "content close";
  }
  if (itemClass === "content close") {
    this.parentNode.className = "content open";
  }
}
sHeader.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", toggleSki);
});
```

```css
.close .list {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.open .list {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  ;
}

.open .arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="content close">

  <div class="header">

    <div class="title">
      <h3>headline</h3>
      <span>Sub title</span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="list grid">

    <div class="data">

      <div class="titles flex">
        <h4 class="name">ABC</h4>
        <p class="number">100%</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bar">
        <div class="perc bg"></div>
        <div class="bar_bg 4d"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome Ben, it's helpful to include all the code so that it's easy to reproduce. There's missing HTML as there's an extra `</div>`, and no `header` or `content` class markup. Please include everything needed to reproduce.

Comment: @Phix There's `class="header"` and `class="content"` markup there, it was just hidden because of formatting issues.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues here. The content shows and hides on click. There's nothing with a class of "arrow" so nothing gets rotated 180 degrees, but that can be added later.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to be more clear about what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Wow, Thank you for your rapid help! I have to check my code. Here it seems to work. I still don´t know why mine won´t work. All i did was remove the actual content and changed some class names.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

in case your code still doesn't run on your environment. I think the problem might be that your for loop misses a variable declaration:

for (**let** i = 0; i < sContent.length; i++)

should solve the difficulties